# Pytorch. Optimizing the input to a model: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed

Tags: pytorch

Currently, I'm trying to optimize the values of an input tensor, x, to a model.
I want to restrict the input to only contain values in the range [0.0;1.0].

There is not too much information about how to do this, when not working with a layer as such.

I've created a minimum working example below, which gives the error message in the title of this post.

**The magic happens in the optimize_x() function**

If I comment out the line: `model.x = model.x.clamp(min=0.0, max=1.0)` the issue is fixed, but the tensor is obviously not clamped.

I'm aware that I could just set `retain_graph=True` - but it's not clear whether this is the right way to go, or if there is a better way of achieving this functionality?

```py
import torch
from torch.distributions import Uniform


class OptimizeInputModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = torch.nn.Sequential(
                torch.nn.Linear(123, 1000),
                torch.nn.Dropout(0.4),
                torch.nn.ReLU(),
                torch.nn.Linear(1000, 100),
                torch.nn.Dropout(0.4),
                torch.nn.ReLU(),
                torch.nn.Linear(100, 1),
                torch.nn.Sigmoid(),
        )

        in_shape = (1, 123)
        self.x = torch.ones(in_shape) * 0.1
        self.x.requires_grad = True

    def forward(self) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.model(self.x)

class MyLossFunc(torch.nn.Module):

    def forward(self, y: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        loss = torch.sum(-y)
        return loss


def optimize_x():
    model = OptimizeInputModel()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam([model.x], lr=1e-4)
    loss_fn = MyLossFunc()
    for epoch in range(50000):
        # Constrain X to have no values < 0
        model.x = model.x.clamp(min=0.0, max=1.0)
        y = model()
        loss = loss_fn(y)

        if epoch % 9 == 0:
            print(f'Epoch: {epoch}\t Loss: {loss}')

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()


optimize_x()
```

Full error message:
`RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future who might have the same question.

My solution was to do (note the underscore!):

```
model.x.data.clamp_(min=0.0, max=1.0)
```

instead of:

```py
model.x = model.x.clamp(min=0.0, max=1.0)
```